# Prove that there are uncountably many repetitve functions $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Call a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ repetitive  if for every finite sequence of natural numbers $(a_1,\ldots a_n)$ there exists a number $k\in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying
>   $$f(k) = a_1, \quad f(k+1)=a_2, \quad \ldots, \quad f(k+n-1) = a_n$$
>
> Prove that there are uncountably many repetitve functions $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$.
>
> (*Hint*: it may help to use the previous exercise, i.e. *'Prove that the set of bijections $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ is uncountable'*)

There also was a subquestion where I had to prove that if $f$ is repetitive then for any $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ there are infinitely manu $k$'s with the property.

I don't see how to prove the uncountability. My first idea was to assume countability and then through a diagonalization argument end up with a contradition. But constructing a function which has the repetitive property seems hard...

Perhaps the hint wants to point at something like an injection from the set of bijections to the set of repetitive numbers. But still this would imply some sort of construction of this repetitive functions. If I have a permutation of $\mathbb{N}$, how could I maps this one-to-one to the set of repetitive functions?

I would prefer hints instead of full solutions.

#### Edit:

Inspired by Omnomnomnom's comment I tried the following:
Let $\mathscr{B} = \{g:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N} \text{ bijections}\}$, and $\mathscr{R} = \{f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N} \text{ repetitive function}\}$, we aim to find a injection $\phi: \mathscr{B}\to \mathscr{R}$, since this would imply uncountable many repetitive functions.

Choose a $f_0\in \mathscr{R}$ and consider $\phi: \mathscr{B}\to \mathscr{R}; g\mapsto g\circ f_0$.

**Is this function well defined?**

I claim that $g\circ f_0$ is repetitive. Let $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ be a sequence of natural numbers, then consider the sequence $(g^{-1}(a_1), g^{-1}(a_2), \ldots, g^{-1}(a_n))$. Since $f_0$ is repetitive we find a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_0(k) = g^{-1}(a_1), \ldots, f_0(k+n-1) = g^{-1}(a_n)$. But then $g\circ f_0(k) = a_1, \ldots, g\circ f_0(k+n-1) = a_n$.

Okay, $g\circ f_0$ is repetitive.

**Is $\phi$ injective?**

Let $g\circ f_0 = h\circ f_0$. Notice how $f_0$ must be surjective, since it is a repetitive function. (Just consider the finite sequence $(a_0)$ for any $a_0\in \mathbb{N}$).

Now choose an $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then there is a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_0(k) = n$. Now consider $g(n) = g(f_0(k)) = g\circ f_0(k) = h\circ f_0(k) = h(n)$. Which implies $g=h$.

Yes $\phi$ is injective, which implies $2^\omega = |\mathscr{B}| \leq |\mathscr{R}|$, i.e. $\mathscr{R}$ is uncountable.

Comment: It might be useful to note that if $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ is a repetitive function and $g: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ is bijective, then $f \circ g$ is also a repetitive function.  However, we can't guarantee that if $g_1,g_2$ are bijections, then $f \circ g_1 = f \circ g_2 \implies g_1 = g_2$.  So, the "obvious" map from the bijections to repetitive functions fails to be one to one.  On the other hand, I'm not sure whether $g \circ f$ is necessarily repetitive.

Comment: Can you come up with an explicit example of a repetitive function? Depending on what your example is, finding uncountably many repetitive functions from it might turn out to be easy.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: shouldn't it be the other way around? If $f$ is repetitive and $g$ bijective, then $g\circ f $ is repetitive? Choose a $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ then there is a $k$ such that $f(k) = g^{-1}(a_1), f(k+1) = g^{-1}(a_2), \ldots$ (?)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I've added a solution inspired by your ideas. I think it checks out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative hint, which may or may not be useful, depending on whether you've heard of the Baire category theorem:

The set $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ of all infinite sequences of natural numbers is a Baire space, and the set of all infinite sequences containing a given sequence $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is a dense open set in $\mathbb N^\mathbb N.$

Answer (score 0):

The hint suggests you find a way to take any function $\Bbb {N \to N}$ and construct a unique repetitive function from it.  Can you construct a single repetitive function $f(n)$?  Can you find a way to mix your $f(n)$ with any $g(n)$ that I give you to make a new function $h(n)$ that is still repetitive?

Comment: So the idea would be that the bijective functions are a subset of all the functions $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ which would be one-to-one to the set of repetitive functions?  Do I need an eplicit single repetitive function $f(n)$? I can't think of a *construction* since this function should contain *any* finite sequence.

Comment: Yes, I would start with an explicit repetitive $f(n)$.  You basically want to enumerate all the finite sequences and string them together.  If your list starts $(1,2), (1,3),(2,4,5)$ you could define $f(0)=1,f(1)=2,f(2)=1,f(3)=3,f(4)=2,f(5)=4,f(6)=5$.  It will be easier if your enumeration is better organized.  Then between each pair of sequences you can insert $0,1$ or $1,0$.  You have countably many insertions, so now have continuum many functions.